# How to store and access JSON objects in arb file in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, localization, arb, flutter-localizations

I am implementing localization in flutter. From what I read in docs I get that all the translations should be in **root/lib/l10n/** folder. I have two files in it **app_en.arb** and **app_hi.arb**. I have followed this official doc on [flutter localization](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization#dart-tools). As I read I got to know that arb file takes **json** format. With the example given in the doc, which takes key-value pair it works fine.

```
{
"helloWorld": "Hello World!",
"@helloWorld": {
      "description": "The conventional newborn programmer greeting"
}                                                                                             
}
```

But what I want is to store json object like this for translation

**app_en.arb**

```
{
"helloWorld": "Hello World!",
"@helloWorld": {
      "description": "The conventional newborn programmer greeting"
},
"content": [
  {
    "id": "one",
    "question": "What's your name?"
  },
  {
    "id": "two",
    "question": "What's your name?"
  }
]  
}
```

**app_hi.arb**

```
{
"helloWorld": "नमस्ते",
"content": [
    {
        "id": "एक",
        "question": "आपका नाम क्या है?"
    },
    {
        "id": "दो",
        "question": "आपका नाम क्या है?"
    }
]                                                                                             
}
```

But it throws an error

> **The value of "content" is not a string.
> Generating synthetic localizations package has failed.**

is it possible to store json objects like this? if not, what is the alternate way?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66743850/how-to-use-run-time-downloaded-localization-arb-json-file-in-flutter) could give an answer to your problem.

Comment: Thanks @ΟυιλιαμΑρκευα but It talks about downloading the localization file at run time. What I want to know is, can't I put **json** objects in arb file? Why it is showing this error?

Answer (score 1):

.arb localization is very opinionated about its format. Therefore having an arbitrary data structure in there does not work because it relies on the Flutter analyzer to parse it and generate a 'FooLocalizations' class inside your .dart_tool/flutter_gen/ folder. If you wanna use an arbitrary JSON format - just create JSON files inside your assets folder and access them via rootbundle.load(path) and serialize the bytes into JSON format :)

Comment: Ok I get it. But can you tell me how to do it without using any third party package?

Comment: rootbundle property is available in Flutter standard library